# Ionic cards scroll x-direction

Tags: ionic-framework, horizontal-scrolling

I am using Ionic Framework to build an Android Application. I need to display horizontally scrollable cards. Each card will display a product image, product title, product price and a button. I tried using ion scroll in x-direction, but cards doesn't seem to scroll in x-direction.

I tried using this [plugin](https://github.com/drewrygh/ionic-ion-horizontal-scroll-cards), but it seems like it can be use only with ion-pane and i am using ion-content.

In the meanwhile, i found another solution -

```
<div class="cardHolder">
                <ul>
                   <div>
                        <img ng-repeat="feature in featured track by $index" ng-src="{{feature.featured_image.source}}" class="examplePic" >
</div>
             </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.cardHolder {
  height: 200px;
  width:100%;
  padding: 8px;
  margin: 6px;
}

ul {
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}


.examplePic {
  height: 150px;
  width: auto;
  border:1px solid black;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

The issue with this solution is that, I am only able to retrieve the image and not the other details.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into ionic's built-in `ion-scroll`. Your code would look something like this. Also checkout this example

```
<ion-scroll direction="x">`
....your scrollable content here...
</ion-scroll>
```

Also checkout this [example](http://codepen.io/garrettmac/pen/RrQqzz)